# Timeout on a WCF call, but getting an HTTP 500(64) error

Tags: c#, wcf, timeout

I've an application (on production environment) that makes a lot of concurrent (multithreading) calls to WCF services (.Net Framework 4.0, SOAP BasicHttpBinding). Sometimes, the last request throws a TimeoutException:

```
System.TimeoutException: The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after...
```

I can't reproduce it on a local envrionment, so it's difficult to apply changes to try. Anyway I've increased the timeout but the exception is throwing equally (later evidently). I've traced the server searching for inter-threading locks or Oracle locks, but I couldn't find anything.

I've activated internal code traces and I've deduced that the request didn't reach my server code, so, watching the IIS traces I've found an HTTP error ~2' after the request:

```
sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
500       0            64              118265
```

But the timeout exceptions is thrown later depending on the wcf binding configuration. So I have two questions:

- Why WCF is not catching that http error and remains waiting for response? I've searched for the error but I have high values on servicethrottling parameters.
- Why the server is throwing that error without getting the server code not even an on an IDispatchMessageInspector I've implemented to log some data on request and response?

Comment: HTTP use TCP as transport layer.  If a TCP message has a bad CRC then the adapter throws away the message before getting to server. But TCP is reliable and will send again update to three times usually the retry is 5 seconds apart.  So I would check your logs and check time between messages to see if there is any gaps.  You can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to get more info.

Comment: You need to deal with errors: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/sending-and-receiving-faults

Comment: thanks @jdweng I've activated diagnostics tracing on WCF but I haven't inspected yet. If I haven't more info, I will try with Fiddler or wireshark.

Comment: @TheobaldDu I'll try to manage better the exceptions but I'm using the same instance on all requests, injected initially via autofac, it would be hard to change... But I only receive the TimeoutException a lot of time after the http 500 error, I think that it won't change...